# Ethers.js metamask request limit exceeded

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask, ethers.js, binance-smart-chain

I’m trying to connect to contracts on BSC, it worked fine for half a year, now it’s starting to give errors, it’s with `contract.on`, when reading something from the contract it works fine
To connect the provider and the signer to work with contracts, I used the default entry for connecting to the metamask from the ethers.js documentation:

`const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum); const signer = provider.getSigner();`

started getting error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw263.png)

tried doing this:

`await window.ethereum.enable() const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum); const signer = provider.getSigner();`

I also tried to connect via rps, but it didn’t happen at all what I needed:
`export const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(settings.bsc.rpcNodeUrl); export const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(settings.wallet.privateKey, provider) export const signer = wallet.connect(provider);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a paid RPC node.

Binance has cut down the APIs and limits of free nodes.

Even better run your own node.

Comment: can you please describe in more detail with code examples, this is new for me, I want to understand

Comment: You need to make an account for commercial service provider e.g. here https://www.quicknode.com/

Comment: Yes, I created an account for myself there and made a node, but how will it all look in the code?

Comment: Because your question does not contain full source code, it is not possible to tell how it will look in your code. I assume you can figure out how to change settings for your own code.

Comment: here is an example of how i use it https://dpaste.org/kVc3Q#L

Comment: That is not a full example. It for example lacks the information how you configure your JSON-RPC connection.

Comment: so I raised my free bsc node for testing, I get this error: https://dpaste.org/sFTow